# Mysql: SELECT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

Sorry for the abysmal title - if someone wants to change it for something more self-explanatory, great - I'm not sure how to express the problem. Which is:

I have a table like so:

```
POST_ID (INT)   TAG_NAME (VARCHAR)

    1              'tag1'
    1              'tag2'
    1              'tag3'
    2              'tag2'
    2              'tag4'
   ....
```

What I want to do is count the number of POSTs which have both tag1 AND tag2.
I've messed about with GROUP BY and DISTINCT and COUNT but I can't construct a query which does the trick.
Any suggestions?

**Edit:** In pseudo sql, the query I want is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(POST_ID) WHICH HAS TAG_NAME = 'tag1' AND TAG_NAME = 'tag2';
```

Thanks

Comment: It'd be helpful to also see what rows you want the query to return, since I'm still not *totally* sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Matchu - in pseudo sql: select post_id which has tag_name = 'tag1' and tag_name = 'tag2';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit: because 'TABLE' was a poor choice for a missing tablename, I'll suppose your table is called `Posts`.

Join the table against itself:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts P1
JOIN Posts P2
ON P1.POST_ID = P2.POST_ID
WHERE P1.TAG_NAME = 'tag1'
AND P2.TAG_NAME = 'tag2'
```

Comment: thanks this looks promising. My actual problem is a little more complicated as my table is not really a table, it's the result of a select+join on two normalised tables.

Comment: @Richard, simply replace in the query the `TABLE` by `(<your query here>)`.

Comment: I think your query should actually be: SELECT * FROM T1
JOIN T1 as T2
ON T1.POST_ID = T2.POST_ID
WHERE T1.TAG_NAME = 'tag1'
AND T2.TAG_NAME = 'tag2'

Comment: @Richard: that is exactly the same query? You didn't supply a tablename, so I used "TABLE" is table name - don't confuse it with the keyword "TABLE". I edited the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) nb_posts
FROM (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) nb_tags
    FROM table
    WHERE tag_name in ('tag1','tag2')
    GROUP BY post_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
  ) t
```

**Edit**: based on Konerak answer, here is the query that handles the case when there are duplicated tag names for a given post:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.post_id
FROM table t1
  JOIN table t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
       AND t2.tag_name = 'tag2'
WHERE t1.tag_name = 'tag1'
```

Comment: What happens when an entry is in the table two times?  1-tag1, 1-tag1?

Comment: @Konerak, when it is the case, do you want to include it into the count, or exclude it ?

Comment: @Konerak: good point. I'm betting it *shouldn't* happen, but it'd probably be best to avoid that possibility if doable. @Bruno: I think the point is that counting is *not* the best solution. Maybe it'd work if you used a DISTINCT somewhere in there, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Matchu, if you want to select the posts and not count them, I think that the query suggested by Konerak is the best solution. But the query as it is does not work if you have duplicated tag names for a given post_id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just leaving this (untested) dependent subquery solution here for reference, even though it'll probably be horribly slow once you get to large data sets. Any solution that does the same thing using joins should be chosen over this.

Assuming you have a `posts` table with an `id` field, as well:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM posts_tags WHERE tag = 'tag1' AND post_id = posts.id) AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM posts_tags WHERE tag = 'tag2' AND post_id = posts.id)
```